# How to create a get request in ASP.NET MVC 5 in AccountController that returns json?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using ASP MVC5 and the built in membership system.  I have modified the IdentityModel to store a "UserToken" field in the user database.  I have created a "UserToken" model as follows in my AccountViewModel.cs

```
public class UserTokenModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "user Token")]
    public string UserToken { get; set;}
}
```

Now in my account Controller I want to use this model so that whenever the user is logged in and goes to the page /Account/GetToken we generate a string and store that string in the UserToken field in our database.  I have created the GetToken class as follows:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult> GetToken(StreamHashModel model)
    {
        var db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        var user = db.Users.First(u => u.UserName == model.UserName);


        user.UserToken = "TEST123456";
        db.Entry(user).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();

        return Json(user.UserToken, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

However my code doesn't work and I get an error saying "Sequence contains no elements".  Looking for any advice on how to get this working.  I feel I am very close to the solution.

Thanks.

Comment: I was able to fix the issue with the help I received.  However now I am having trouble using the [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] attribute for this method.  I get an error saying 

"The required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present."

Looking for advice on how to remedy that.  TY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query `db.Users.First(u => u.UserName == model.UserName)` does not return any thing. so if you want return current logged in user try this query:

```
db.Users.Single(u => u.UserName == User.Identity.Name);
```

Answer (score 2):

The "sequence contains no elements" is probably coming from this line:

```
var user = db.Users.First(u => u.UserName == model.UserName);
```

Which will throw an exception if no username matches. Try FirstOrDefault() then handle null, or put the First() in a try...catch and handle accordingly.